# Trajectory Planning not working reliably

Tags: ros, motion-planning, moveit, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get the Trac-IK to work, since the default solver didn't work very well for me.
But now that I'm using Trac-IK, there is no real improvement. It only finds a solution 1 in 5 times, and takes up to more than a second to find the solution. This differs alot from the values given on [Trac-IK](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/overview) for 6-DOF arms.

So I suppose i have some issue with my robot, but I'm unable to spot it.
My setup is fairly simple: a [robot](https://github.com/mas-group/schunk_modular_robotics/blob/indigo_dev/schunk_description/urdf/lwa4p/lwa4p.urdf.xacro) on a table with a simple gripper.

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. I'm 100% sure, that there must be a possible solution to the planning problem, but my move_group keeps on crashing!

Any Idea what could be a possible problem? maybe joint-limits?

Edit: Also, when planning fails, the move_group process dies quite frequently...

Edit 2: today i tried the IK-Fast plugin, which is unfortunately also unable to plan paths for my robot.

Can anyone give me a hint for where to look for problems in my robot setup?
I've uploaded the moveit_config with urdf files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hvzvQQnsOyNHZFWUlMamRrX2c/view?usp=sharing)

Edit 3: I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_modular_robotics/issues/188) on schunk_modular_robotics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261301/trajectory-planning-not-working-reliably/) by [David_111](https://answers.ros.org/users/30233/david_111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-15**:
I think it'd be good if you could describe what setup you have. I see `LWA 4p` in your tags, so I'm guessing you have a 6-dof manipulator. Barring any really weird kinematic structures, that should work well with Trac-IK. Can you perhaps make your MoveIt cfg pkgs available?

**Comment by [David_111](https://answers.ros.org/users/30233/david_111/) on 2017-05-16**:
I uploaded the MoveIt config [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-hvzvQQnsOyWVZhcm1SZ3YtelU). Do you need anything else?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-22**:
I can't download your package: google drive complains that it can't zip all files, and I'm not going to download them all separately.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-22**:
Also: without your `item_workcell` package I can't really test this, as I can't actually start your moveit config.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-23**:
I've quickly tested your configuration: in general I would suggest adding explicit `collision` geometry to everything.

As to your planning problems: even with just the robot in isolation moveit seems to have trouble finding successful plans. I can't comment on whether that is due to joint limits ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-23**:
.. but I doubt it has anything to do with the specific IK plugin you're using.

As to `move_group` crashing: I've not seen that at all, but I've only used `demo.launch` and the RViz plugin.

You might want to post an issue on the `schunk_modular_robotics` issue tracker to see whether other users ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-23**:
.. have trouble with MoveIt and this particular robot.

For crashes, always make sure that you don't have any partial upgrades of ROS (ie: oustanding upgrades of specific packages), and that you rebuild your workspace after *every* upgrade of packages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-23**:
Just remembered btw: it looks like this robot is able to rotate its joints such that it rotates into itself. That can lead to problems, as motion planners will have to figure out how to 'cross the gap' going from one half of the allowed joint rotation limit to the other. I'm not sure whether that ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-23**:
.. is a problem here, but see [ros-industrial/universal_robot#265](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/265) for a similar issue.

This would be something to ask about on the `schunk_modular_robotics` issue tracker.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-23**:\

> I have opened an issue on schunk_modular_robotics.

would be nice if you could include a link to that issue then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For now adjusting the joint limits did the trick... almost.

Working with these Joint Limits ..

- Joint: 1 -2.9 2.9
- Joint: 2 -2.9 2.9
- Joint: 3 -2.7 2.7
- Joint: 4 -2.9 2.9
- Joint: 5 -2.9 2.9
- Joint: 6 -2.9 2.9

... greatly improved the rate of succesful motion plans.
Thanks @gvdhoorn!

---

Originally posted by [David_111](https://answers.ros.org/users/30233/david_111/) with karma: 32 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0